# How to get element ID dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a major div which holds a group of divs. when divs inside are selected, I need to get their id in a dynamically way.
I tried a few options but i got Not a number or Undifined.

//HTML

```
<div class="ui-selectable" id="Sunday" style="width: 100px; float: left;">
 Sunday
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="100" >1 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="200" > 2 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="300" > 3 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="400" > 4 </div>
    <div class="ui-selectee" id="500"> 5 </div>    
</div>
```

//jquery

```
 $("#Sunday").selectable({
            stop: function () {
                  var result = $("#select-result").empty();              
                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
            ***      var index = $("#Sunday DIV").children("Div").prop('id'); - option 1
            ***     var index = $("#Sunday DIV").children("Div").id; -  option 2
            ***     var index = $("#Sunday DIV").children("Div").attr("id") -  option 3
                       result.append(index);                      
                });}});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are appending `id` in `#select-result` div. Do you want to append all the ids or all the elements ?

Comment: All the ids, i already got all elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` inside `each()` will resolve to the element you are interested in, try this:

```
$(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
}
```

Comment: you can use `this.id` as well

Comment: I was on cruise control - you are correct and this is the fastest way to retrieve the `id`

Answer (score 0):

this will also work

```
$(".ui-selectee").each(function( index, element ) {
    // element == current element
    var id = $(element).attr("id");
});
```